# React span space in between text

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-table

I'm trying to add a space between span and text in React but it seems it behaves differently in JSX? here is the code

```
return(
    <div>
         <h1 className="navbar"> <span style={styles}> {timeOfDay} </span> 
          {`${firstName} ${lastName}`} It is currently {hours} clock</h1>
    </div>
    )
```

[image: span]
As you can see {timeOfDay} which is good night is sticking to the text, what im trying to do is have a space between them, how can i achieve that in React?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to add space between elements in JSX

1. Use `&nbsp;`

```js
    return(
       <div>
         <h1 className="navbar"> <span style={styles}> {timeOfDay} </span> 
          &nbsp;{`${firstName} ${lastName}`} It is currently {hours} clock</h1>
      </div>
    )
```

2. Use `{' '}`

```js
    return(
       <div>
         <h1 className="navbar"> <span style={styles}> {timeOfDay} </span> 
          {` ${firstName} ${lastName}`} It is currently {hours} clock</h1>
      </div>
    )
```

3. Use CSS(padding/margin to span)